# Irreducible hypersurfaces over $\mathbb{C}$ that are not regular in codimension one

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, singularity-theory

Let $V = V(f) \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ be an irreducible (affine) hypersurface. The singular locus $\text{Sing}(V)$ of $V$ is the set of points in $V$ where all the partial derivatives of $f$ vanish. I am interested in examples where $\dim(\text{Sing}(V)) = n-2$, i.e. the singular locus has codimension one.

There are two classes of easy examples. One is when $V = V' \times \mathbb{C}^{n-2}$ for a non-smooth algebraic curve $V$, i.e. $f$ is a polynomial in two variables and has singularities. The other is when $f$ is a homogenous polynomial in three variables and has singularities (this feels like the "projective version" of the previous case).

1. Are there other examples of irreducible complex hypersurfaces that have a codimension one singular locus?
2. If there are, are there general conditions that imply that the singular locus has codimension at least two? (It is unclear, of course, what it means for a condition to be "general"; I'm hoping for one which does not involve explicitly checking the partial derivatives of the polynomial.)

Comment: Is there an automoprhism of $\Bbb{C}^3$ sending $x^2z+y^2$ to $f(x,y)$ ?

Comment: With regards to the second question, yes there is a general condition, namely being a normal variety. This is a standard assumption in algebraic geometry, maybe pick a text book that you like and read more about it.